# Summing Ranges In VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am not very versed in coding so this may not be correct lingo, but I am trying to do a very simple thing, sum ranges. By that I mean I want:

```
Sub Test()
Range("E2:E9") = Range("D2:D9") + Range("G2:G9")
End Sub
```

This works fine if I only use:

```
Sub Test()
Range("E2") = Range("D2") + Range("G2")
End Sub
```

From this all I want to happen is get everything in cells E2-E9 to be equal to its relative addition of D_ and G_. So E4 will equal D4+G4 for example.

This is just a test for a larger project with 100+ rows which is why I don't want to do them all manually.

Maybe I need to use some sort of array addition or something? I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Range Object Formula` property like this:

**Edit1:** Avoid circular ref as what Mark Balhoff pointed out

```
With Range("E2:E9")
    .Offset(0, 2).Value = .Offset(0, 2).Value '~~> avoid circular ref
    .Formula = "=D2+G2"
    .Value = .Value
    .Offset(0, -1).ClearContents
    .Offset(0, 2).Formula = "=E2" '~~> if you still want to have it reflected in G
End With
```

Or you can add D to E directly without using a helper column G.

```
With Range("E2:E9")
    .Offset(0, -1).Copy '~~> copy what's in D
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd '~~> add in E
    .Offset(0, -1).ClearContents '~~> clear whatever's in D
End With
```

Comment: This didn't quite work. I also forgot the fact that I want it to continue to count. Sorry, hit enter too soon.

What I also need is, if I delete what is in D2, the value in E2 will not change. So, I need to sum the current numbers, and make them stay persistently in E2, so when new number is entered into D2, E2 will increase by that number

Comment: @David I'm confused :) Do you want to increase the value in E as D change or not. Your comment seems contradicting in a way. If you don't want it to change and just change it when Macro is run, see my edit.

Comment: Let me 100% start over, as I possibly came about this all wrong from the start.

I want to be able to track rebuilds of a part. So, say part A gets rebuilt today, I want to be able to put a 1 in a cell, and have a running total of how many times I put a 1 there be tracked. So I will make a macro button later on to clear that input cell after each "1". Thus, every time a part is repaired, we will have a running total of how many times without having to do manual math.

Does this make more sense?

My original way worked, but only row by row, which is bad code.

Comment: What I had in my G column of cells was for instance in G2, I had "=E2". With my row by row code this would then take what was in D2, add it to G2 (which was my last counts total as G2=E2) and then add them together. This is probably why I was misunderstood, I didn't state how my cells and code were set up. Sorry for that.

Comment: @David No worries. Just be specific next time :) Btw, does my edit work for you? I didn't include the clearing of D though. Also, how do you populate D?

Comment: No this didn't work either. I populate with a manual input of 1. There may even be better system all together. I am trying to develop a very simple easy to use system for a worker to use to keep track of rebuilds. Basically, rows A-C are part info (model #, make, description) D is where I plan to have them put a 1 if a rebuild is done. Currently E is where the running tally is kept. Honestly, any way to accomplish this running tally would be fine. I just need to be able to set row D to null and retain the running tally, and when a 1 is put into say D4, E4 will increase by 1 when I run macro.

Comment: @David I don't see why it shouldn't work for your case. But what it does is sum up the current values in D and G to it's corresponding row in E everytime the macro is ran. Also, I added a line which clears D when macro runs. If this is what you want done, then the above code should work. If not, it may help if you can revise your question and add additional specifics for us to help you better. :)

Comment: @David if the formula in G2 is =E2 as you stated above and both of the answers are trying to put in E2 the formula =D2+G2 you will get a circular reverence error between E2 and G2.

Comment: @David My bad, Mark is right. You'll have a circular reference. See my edit then.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how you would do it as an array function:

```
Range("E2:E9").FormulaArray = "=D2:D9+G2:G9"
```

But array functions can be unwieldy, so you might just want to do it as single-cell formulas:

```
Range("E2:E9").Formula = "=D:D+G:G"
```

Excel does a little bit of magic to make that formula work. If you want to be explicit:

```
Range("E2:E9").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]+RC[2]"
```

Comment: +1. I'm intrigued about how `Range("E2:E9").Formula = "=D:D+G:G"` works.

Comment: IDK but I think this does not solve the circular reference @MarkBalHoff pointed out. No offense to upvoters nor to rdhs but I'll still give credit to Mark. If he's to post his comment as an answer, I'd gladly delete mine :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom formula to do so.

For e.g. you want to sum **A1:A10** and **B1:B10** and need the results in **C1:C10** (do note that you'll need the same number of rows here, and both vertical)

```
Sub AddRanges(Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range, ResultRng As Range)
    Dim i As Long, N As Long
    N = Rng1.Rows.Count

    For i = 1 To N
        ResultRng(i, 1).Value = Rng1(i, 1).Value + Rng2(i, 1).Value
    Next i
End Sub
```

This formula calls the above subroutine

```
Sub TestMyFormula()
    Dim RngA As Range, RngB As Range, RngC As Range
    Set RngA = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A10")
    Set RngB = ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B10")
    Set RngC = ActiveSheet.Range("C1:C10")

    Call AddRanges(RngA, RngB, RngC)

End Sub
```